# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute a query in my Oracle database with a WHERE clause:

```
java.sql.Date today = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

String sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT *")
                    .append("FROM USERNAME.MY_TABLE m")
                    .append("WHERE m.A_DATE_COLUMN = ?").toString();

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setDate(1, today);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

But I keep getting error:

> SQL command not properly ended

when `executeQuery()` is called.  I know it has to do with setting my parameters because the query runs fine and returns the proper data if I don't include the WHERE clause. The table I am querying from has just the one column which is of type DATE.

I tried using `setString` instead of `setDate` and adding a semicolon after `?` inside my String I use to create my query, but it's my understanding I don't want to include a semicolon.

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Have you tried to output the string before executing it???  I can tell from the strings that you miss spaces.

Comment: Unrelated, but: the use of a StringBuilder for a constant String is useless.

Comment: You are missing a space after the `*` and before the `FROM` inside the String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add spaces:

```
String sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * ")
                    .append("FROM USERNAME.MY_TABLE m ")
                    .append("WHERE m.A_DATE_COLUMN = ? ").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

After the append, your query looks like below.

```
SELECT *FROM USERNAME.MY_TABLE mWHERE m.A_DATE_COLUMN = ?
```

Add the spaces properly.

```
String sql = new StringBuilder("SELECT * ")
                .append("FROM USERNAME.MY_TABLE m ")
                .append("WHERE m.A_DATE_COLUMN = ?").toString();
```